# How to Google in Python Using urllib or requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, urllib, google-search

What is the proper way to Google something in Python 3? I have tried `requests` and `urllib` for a Google page. When I simply `res = requests.get("https://www.google.com/#q=" + query)` that doesn't come back with the same HTML as when I inspect the Google page in Safari. The same happens with `urllib`. A similar thing happens when I use Bing. I am familiar with `AJAX`. However, it seems that that is now depreciated.

Comment: You had better use Selenium (to simulate a real browser headless or not) instead of requests (just downloading plain HTML if response mimetype is so).

Answer (score 0):

In python, if you do not specify the user agent header in http requests manually, python will add for you by default which can be detected by Google and may be forbidden by it.

Try the following if it can help.

```
import urllib
yourUrl = "post it here"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}  
req = urllib.request.Request(yourUrl, headers = headers)
page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: Well at first it said `urllib has no attribute urlopen` but that's an easy fix its just `urllib.requests.urlopen`

Comment: @DylanSiegler.This is mainly because you use python3 but my code is python2.So i will change it to python3.Retry it.

Comment: What is query in `urllib.request.Request(query, headers=headers)`? Is it just what I want to Google?

Comment: Yes.Because i haven't installed python3 in my computer, so i just typed it. If it has some syntax error, just replace it.

Comment: When I try this out using the word test (https://www.google.com/#q=test) it still doesn't come up with the correct results. I tried printing out the text and searching for `class="r"`, which is what all of the regular links are,it came up with nothing.Here is my code `import urllib
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}
url = "https://www.google.com/#q=test"
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
mydivs = soup.findAll("h3", {"class": "r"})
print(mydivs)`